Razorpay TypeError: this[("on" + t)] is not a function
I am integrating Razorpay into my React application using the
 in `index.html`. 
It was worked Fine, but now today I am getting.
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Script error.
at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:154495:58)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:154514:7
at Console:
Uncaught TypeError: this[("on" + t)] is not a function
at Ye.onmessage (checkout.js:1:158735)
is the Problem lies in the Razorpay Side link  ?
Why this was occurring and How to Avoid These Errors When Using  Cdn Links..?

I encountered the same issue yesterday, but it resolved itself today without any changes. It might have been a temporary problem with the Razorpay CDN. If the issue persists, try clearing the browser cache or check if there are any updates on the Razorpay side.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

From your index.html remove
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>

and replace it with
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>


What's the change, adding type? Then I'm reasonably certain that it's not going to help, since text/javascript is the default one.

Now the issue Resolved Automatically ...  Thankyou all For your Response
